# Why am I getting "builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python

Given my `interleave` function below:

```
def interleave(L1, L2):
    if len(L1) == 1:
        return [L1[0], L2[0]]
    else:
        return [L1[0], L2[0]].extend(interleave(L1[1:], L2[1:]))
```

Why does it produce the error `builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`?

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
return [L1[0], L2[0]].extend(interleave(L1[1:], L2[1:]))
```

`.extend(` returns `None` as it mutates its object.

Use either:

```
return [L1[0], L2[0]] + interleave(L1[1:], L2[1:])
```

Or:

```
l = [L1[0], L2[0]]
l.extend(interleave(L1[1:], L2[1:]))
return l
```